# Facebook-style CSS sliding panel doesn't scroll on iOS

Tags: ios, css, iphone

I created a mobile version of my website, testing along the way on my Nexus 5. After testing on iOS 7 (on an iPhone4 and iPhone5S), seems like scrolling on the side menu is broken.

Here's a live demo (no links work, and you'll see a huge CSS & JS file, since it's for the whole app): http://www.altertecnia.com/menu/

Click on the top left icon, and the menu is displayed. Now, on desktop and Android, I can scroll the whole page (including the menu) just fine, and click on the right side of the menu to close it. But on iOS7, when I try to do that, only the background (content of the page) scrolls, not the menu.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Probably not related but you have a missing < on the Vista Escritorio link in your nav footer.

Comment: @BillyMoat I don't see it.. what browser are you using?